# collectionViewCell not showing - cellForItemAtIndexPath not being called (programmatically)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am making a calendar (just started). I have decided to try to do it completely programmatically but for some strange reason I am able to show the `collectionView` backgroundColor but when I add cells, they are not showing. it seems to me that everything is properly set up. In the picture, the white background is the collectionView and the red background is the view that contains it. The yellow cell are not being showed though.

My `WeekView` class

```
class WeekView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

lazy var collectionView:UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.directionalLockEnabled          = true
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator    = false
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator  = false
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return cv
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setup(){

    addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.leftAnchor, constant: 50).active = true
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topAnchor, constant: 50).active = true
    collectionView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.rightAnchor).active = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.heightAnchor).active = true

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 150
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50)
}

}
```

My `ViewController` class

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

setUpLeftMenuView()
    setupCalendar()
}

var menuBar:SideMenuView = {
    let menuBar = SideMenuView()
    return menuBar
}()

func setUpLeftMenuView(){

    self.view.addSubview(menuBar)
    menuBar.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
    menuBar.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
    menuBar.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100).active = true
    menuBar.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor).active = true
}

var calendarView:WeekView = {
   let cv = WeekView()
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return cv
}()

func setupCalendar() {

    view.addSubview(calendarView)
    calendarView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(menuBar.rightAnchor).active = true
    calendarView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
    calendarView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor).active = true
    calendarView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor).active = true
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try calling `reloadData` at the end of `setup`.

Comment: @Michael I tried, unfortunately still nothing! Any other thoughts?

Comment: Either put a breakpoint or print inside `numberOfItemsInSection` to see if it's being called. Actually, you're doing it all in `init`, which doesn't look like a good idea. Try moving the code to `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @Michael yes, it is being called

Comment: `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not being called though

Comment: Did you set the collection view data source/delegate?

Comment: @RobertMasen thanks... yes I did

Comment: I think it is something about my constraints since `numberOfItemsInSection` is being called but I don't have any error in the console

Comment: @mat That's possible. UICollectionView won't call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` until it begins to render a cell. If there's no room for the cell, it won't be called. Is there a reason you're not using Interface Builder?